# Changing footer information

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a set of individual pages.  The footer of each page has a button reading "Sign in" which, when tapped, leads the user to the login page. If the login is successful, the user is moved to a different page; if not, they are returned to the login page.

I want to be able to change the "Sign in" label to "Sign out" and its href to the logout page when a successful login occurs. But I don't seem to be able to reference the element.

The html in the footer element is:

```
<a class="inout ui-link ui-btn" rel="external" href="login.php">
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Log in</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Running a simple jq command such as

```
$('a.inout').attr('href','logout.php');
```

when the user arrives at the "successful login" page fails to connect.

I'm missing something - I'd appreciate some illumination.

Thanks/B

Comment: When are you calling $('a.inout').attr('href','logout.php');? Is it on pagebeforeshow of each page?

Comment: Thanks - that was the key I needed. How to I credit you?

Comment: You are welcome. I added it as an answer so you can accept it and let future searchers know that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the call in the jQM pagebeforeshow event handler, so as each new page is loaded, the footer button will be updated:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pageid", function(){

    $('a.inout').prop('href','logout.php');

});
```